# How To Configure webRTC And Express.js To Run In Same Domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express, webrtc

I'm looking to have a video conference website running on node.js + express.js instead of regular apache and I'm having trouble deciding on a solution.

I need the server to send the website to the user through express.js, plus, connect people in a queue so they can enter a video conference with strangers.

Should I build two different server applications, one for the express.js and one for the webRTC server, listening on different ports?
If so, how can I make the user interact with the different aplications? They will need to be able to login, be placed in the queue and be able to see the strangers once the connection is established.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebRTC and Express.js is differ ExpressJS (Web frame work mapping your request)
but WebRTC is differ(Peer-to-Peer) communication with the help of signalling means exchange information about two browser so you can use Socket.IO or any other websocket framework

Every thing depend of signalling you want to connect particular person send signalling that particular person its not possible in Express.js so use any websocket framework like socket.io